# How do the sine and cosine functions encode position in the transformer?

Tags: deep-learning, natural-language-processing, transformer, attention, positional-encoding

After going through both the "[Illustrated Transformer](http://jalammar.github.io/illustrated-transformer/)" and "[Annotated Transformer](http://nlp.seas.harvard.edu/2018/04/03/attention.html)" blog posts, I still don't understand how the sinusoidal encodings are representing the position of elements in the input sequence.

Is it the fact that since each row (input token) in a matrix (entire input sequence) has a unique waveform as its encoding, each of which can be expressed as a linear function of any other element in the input sequence, then the transformer can learn relations between these rows via linear functions?

Comment: [What is the positional encoding in the transformer model?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/51065/10640). The explanation therein may help you.